VBA: Pasting Multiple Ranges into Word Doc in Order
Sub Test_Pictures()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("01")
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("Report01_1")
    Set rng2 = ws.Range("Report01_2")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    
    With wordDoc.Range
    
        rng1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        wordDoc.Content.Paste
        wordDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    
        rng2.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        wordDoc.Content.InsertAfter vbCr
        wordDoc.Content.Paste
    End With
    
End Sub

I am trying to paste multiple "pictures" of named ranges from my workbook ontop of one another into a word doc. However, it seems that the "rng2" image overwrites the "rng1" image every time I run the macro.
In Word, only the "rng2" image shows, and if I Ctrl+Z, the "rng1" image shows which leads me to believe this image is being overwritten. Any ideas on a fix for this?

The 2nd wordDoc.Content.Paste replaces the content of Doc (include the first picture) with a new picture (the 2nd).
Try
    With wordDoc.Content 
        rng1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .Paste
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        rng2.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .Characters.Last.Paste
    End With

OR
    With wordDoc.Content 
        rng1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .Paste
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        wordApp.Selection.endKey Unit:=6
        rng2.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        wordApp.Selection.Paste
    End With



Awesome! Thank you so much for your help. Exactly what I needed

You could use just:
With wordDoc.Range
    rng1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    .Paste
    .Collapse 0 'wdCollapseEnd    
    rng2.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    .Paste
End With

This will give you two pics, one after the other, with no space between them.

This works for me:
Sub Test_Pictures()

    Dim wordApp As Object, wordDoc As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0 'you want to see an error if the next part fails!
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    End If
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    
    
    CopyRangePicToWord [A1:D8], wordDoc
    CopyRangePicToWord [F1:I8], wordDoc
   
End Sub

Sub CopyRangePicToWord(rng As Range, doc As Object)
    'move selection to end of content
    doc.Application.Selection.EndKey unit:=6, Extend:=0 '6=wdStory,0=wdMove
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    doc.Application.Selection.Paste 'paste at selection
    doc.content.InsertParagraphAfter
End Sub

